# Handling value rollover in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm processing a dataframe that contains a column that consists of an error count. The problem I'm having is the counter rolls over after 64k. Additionally, on long runs the rollover occurs multiple times. I need a method to correct these overflows and get an accurate count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it always work correctly, but let's try:

```
# groups
g = df.groupby((df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum())

# mapping cumulative summand
mp = df.groupby((df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum(), as_index=False).max().shift(1).fillna(0)['count']

# math
for grp, chunk in g:
    df['count'] += (df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum().map(mp)
```

Original DF:

```
In [416]: df
Out[416]:
    count
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       0
7       1
8       2
9       3
10      4
11      0
12      1
13      2
14      3
15      4
16      5
17      6
18      7
19      8
```

Result:

```
In [414]: df
Out[414]:
    count
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     5.0
6     5.0
7     6.0
8     7.0
9     8.0
10    9.0
11    9.0
12   10.0
13   11.0
14   12.0
15   13.0
16   14.0
17   15.0
18   16.0
19   17.0
```

Explanation:

helper for grouping (monotonically increasing groups):

```
In [418]: (df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum()
Out[418]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
17    2
18    2
19    2
Name: count, dtype: int32
```

Summand for each group:

```
In [420]: df.groupby((df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum(), as_index=False).max().shift(1).fillna(0)['count']
Out[420]:
0    0.0
1    5.0
2    4.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

already mapped summands - they will be added `N` times (where `N` is number of groups - `3` for this example):

```
In [421]: (df['count'].diff() < 0).cumsum().map(mp)
Out[421]:
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     5.0
7     5.0
8     5.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
11    4.0
12    4.0
13    4.0
14    4.0
15    4.0
16    4.0
17    4.0
18    4.0
19    4.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

setup test DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': np.arange(20)})
df.ix[6:10, 'count'] = range(5)
df.ix[11:19, 'count'] = range(9)
```